# Cliente Soap usando wsdl y Genivia en C, "cc" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Tags: c, soap, wsdl

estoy usando el toolkit de Genivia para generar un client Soap en lenguaje C. Seguí las instrucciones de su sitio (https://www.genivia.com/examples/calc/index.html). Traté de replicar el ejemplo del Calculador, sin embargo cuando ejecuto el comando:

`cc -o calcclient calcclient.c stdsoap2.c soapC.c soapClient.c`

Ocurre el siguiente error:

> "cc" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.**

En fin, lo que yo realmente necesito es generar un ejemplo sencillo de cliente soap en C a partir de un wsdl. Por lo que me sirve en cualquier caso ayuda para solucionar el error que expuse o ayuda con otra forma de generar el cliente.

Estaré realmente agradecido si alguien puede ayudarme.

Comment: Estás en StackOverflow en Español, por favor, edita la pregunta y traducela al español para que pueda ser respondida.

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo y compilador de C estás tratando de usar?

Comment: Estoy en windows. Por ahora solo he seguido las instrucciones del sitio a través de comandos

Comment: Si has instalado un compilador de C y éste no se reconoce sin teclear la ruta absoluta es porque ésta no está incluida en el `PATH`. Para poder modificar éste debes conocer antes la ruta donde está el compilador de C. ¿Qué compilador es, dónde lo has instalado y dónde está el archivo `cc.exe`? PD: Estoy viendo en los ejemplos que todo parece estar orientado a trabajar con Linux. Los archivos ejecutables se llaman precediéndolos con `./`, siendo `/` el separador de rutas UNIX, y no Windows.

Comment: Tengo instalado CLion de JBrains. En la ruta C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.3.4. Lo unico es que no logro ubicar el cc.exe dentro de esta carpeta. Tienes alguna sugerencia de compilador que se ajuste mas a mi necesidad

Comment: Las preguntas en este sitio, solo deben ir en español.

Comment: He removido la parte en inglés de la pregunta, ya que es innecesaria.

Comment: Por si solo CLion no es capaz de compilar código, necesita de una serie de herramientas que deben instalarse por separado: [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html). Cuando completes la instalación del entorno de compilación tendrás disponible el compilador para hacer el trabajo que deseas.